# Why is water not rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a simple water setup: water flowing into a basin.  In edit mode, I can see the wireframe of the water, but once it is rendered, I don't see anything. What is going on here?  [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwFJHyT6aOp3X08yZ282VWRsUnc) is my .blend

Comment: Please check you file permissions, I don't think we have download access

Comment: I can download it.  What makes you think you can't.

Comment: Now I can download it, when i first accessed the file it was asking for a password or different google account. Anyway you could always download it even if the permissions were not right, you are the owner of the file after all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two distinct problems with your water not being renderable, one for the viewport preview other for the final render.

- **Viewport** - In the viewport the water simulation is invisible because it's *Maximum Draw Type* is set to *Wire* - Under the *Properties Window > Object Tab > Display Panel* change the *Maximum Draw Type* from *Wire* to *Solid* or *Textured*
- **Final Render** Your domain is set to non renderable in the outliner - Go to the outliner and set it renderable by clicking the camera icon